# Find the area of surface generated by revolving the curve a bout y-axis?

Tags: calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

> Find the area of surface generated by revolving the curve  $$x= \int_{0}^{y} \tan t \ dt, \ 0 \leq y \leq\frac {\pi}{3}$$
>   about the $y$-axis

My try

$$\frac {dx}{dy}=\tan y \to \left(\frac {dx}{dy}\right)^2=(\tan y)^2$$

$$ S= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \int_{0}^{y} \tan t ~dt ~\sqrt {1+(\tan y)^2} ~dy$$

$$ S= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \int_{0}^{y} \tan t ~dt ~\sec y ~dy $$

I am stuck here , What should I do now?

Comment: $\int_0^y \tan t \ dt = -\ln |\cos y|.$  But I am not sure that helps as $-\int \frac {\ln |\cos y|}{|\cos y|} \ dy$ is nothing nice.

Comment: The anti-derivative is non-elementary, and the definite integral doesn't appear to have an analytic solution. The numerical value is $\sim 2\pi \cdot 0.330303$

Comment: @Dylan  how to get numerical value?

Comment: I just plugged it into Wolfram Alpha